# Dynamic SQL queries for Postgres and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, plpgsql

What is the difference in writing something like this:

```
SET SCHEMA 'schema';
        SELECT  table2.field1,
                table2.field2,
                table2.field3,
                table2.field4,
                table2.field5,
                table2.field6
            FROM table2
            WHERE table2.field1 LIKE '%{$search}%' and table2.field2 LIKE '%{$search2}%' and table2.field3 LIKE '%{$search3}%' and table2.field4 LIKE '%{$search4}%' and (table2.field5 ~* '{$search5}' {$radioa} table2.field6 ~* '{$search6}') 
            ORDER BY table1.field1 DESC, table1.field2 LIMIT {$radiob};
```

And something in plpgsql? What I mean is will I benefit in speed or efficiency anymore if I translated the above to plpgsql? Should I stick to the bland, dynamic statement in PHP, or go bananas with plpgsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution time of queries are same in both cases. Is not important if you run the query from client of from PLpgSQL. The difference is in result processing. When you process result in server side (from PLpgSQL), then the network and data type conversions overhead is zero. The data processing on client side is much more expensive - for frequently called queries or large result is processing on client side significantly slower.

Other benefit of stored procedure (server side code) is accessibility from heterogeneous environment (you can share this code well). PHP code you can call simply only from PHP or via HTTP protocol. But this advantage is not significant in monolithic environments (all is Java or all is PHP).

Comment: Oooo the universal code part is a very good point. Thank you.